# Tap gesture not working for me

Tags: ios, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am getting started with this [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1).

So I created a Tap Gesture by drag and drop on Image View, Then I control-drag into my `UIViewControler` and the Event (Action) is created successfully.

But my problem is that it is not firing the event. Is there any other thing I have to do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]

You must set USER Interaction Enabled of UIImage view from storyboard/xib

Check mark User Interaction Enabled under "Interaction"

Comment: From where? I'm very very new

Comment: I have attached screen shot,did you find this?

Comment: StackOverFlow dont allow me to accepted under 10 min, Sorry for delay man and thank you again

Comment: Copy from the tutorial: "In the Attributes inspector, find the field labeled Interaction and select the User Interaction Enabled checkbox.
You’ll need this feature later to let users interact with the image view."

Comment: Thanks so much - somehow, I missed this in the tutorial!

Comment: Thank you so much!